# Saving photo in Messages to camera roll

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

I am trying to save a picture onto my camera roll, but when I message or email the picture to myself and try to save (click on the box with an arrow) the only options I get are to copy, print, or save to Dropbox. I want this picture for my wallpaper, but will need to get it off of camera roll to do that. How do I save the photo to my camera roll?

Comment: I've answered below, but it sounds like you're transferring it from one of your devices to another—AirDrop is probably easier, if both devices are new enough to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply press and hold the image thumbnail and tap "Save".

A copy will be saved to your camera roll.

[image]